# Hide div based on user ID?

Tags: javascript, php, joomla

I'll get right into it. I need to hide some content on a page using PHP and Javascript.

I'm using Joomla. Here is the table:

```
<table class="orders">
<tr>
<th>Name</th>
<div class="testclass"><th>Expiry Date</th>
<th>Batch ID</th></div>
<th>Local ICOS</th>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>...</td>
<div class="testclass"><td>...</td>
<td>...</td></div>
<td>...</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Now, let's say I want to hide "Expiry Date" and "Batch ID" for the user whose user ID is 50. This is the code I have written for that:

```
<?php 
$user = Jfactory::getUser();
$userID = $user->get(id);

if ($userID == "50") {
echo "<script type='text/javascript>'
$(document).ready(function(){
$('.testclass').show();  
})
</script>";
}

else {
echo "<script type='text/'javascript>'
$(document).ready(function(){
$('.testclass').hide();
})
</script>";
}

?>
```

Now, my page does load so there are no errors. However, it still does not physically hide the div's where the class is "testclass".

It just displays them normally. I know a better way is to use groups and I am going to assign the selected users on our site the required groups.

SO I think to call the groups might be easier instead of doing it for all the user ID's.

This is the only thing left for the completion of this custom "default.php" of a component I'm using. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: you want to hide it, but in your code ID - 50 is showing the class, not hiding it.

Comment: Why don't you do this using PHP instead? Meaning use PHP to do the if statement...

Comment: AND that is not a good way of doing it. Don't just change css style using JS. anyone with common knowledge can change css code. If you want to really hide it, then don't load the html code if userID is the one you dont want to see that stuff!

Comment: Hi @MikelisBaltruks. You said this: ". If you want to really hide it, then don't load the html code if userID is the one you dont want to see that stuff!" could you elaborate more on that or give an example using this code of mine?

Comment: hey. i just checked my old answer. if it worked, you should accept it as a correct one or specify something that doesn't work. (so the question could be closed).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

FOA - Your code has it mixed - when userID is 50, the code is showing (`.show()`) the class elements, not hiding them. 
Second - Don't hide things using Javascript as anyone with access to dev tools (so anyone) can change the css and see the code. 
Better way is not to render the code at all. It would go sth like this:

```
<table class="orders">     
    <tr>
      <th>Name</th>
      <?php if ($user->id!="50") { ?>
         <th>Expiry Date</th>
         <th>Batch ID</th>
      </div>
      <?php } ?>
      <th>Local ICOS</th>
   </tr>
</table>
```

You can hide stuff using JS when it's not important and is just for convenience for the user not to see them. Don't do that with important stuff.

Plus, your JS code is not correct in both parts. It should start like:

```
echo "<script type='text/javascript'> ... "
```

Notice the quatation marks.

Comment: Thanks for the tips and advice.I see what you mean by I'm literally showing the div if user ID is 50. I will give your version a try! I actually tried to use it in the way you did and it was at least loading.

Comment: you should definately do it with serverside tools, not clientside. If (for example) you show some page and would hide information from non-admins with javascript, that would be a really big no-no as anyone with common knowledge could access that info. :)

Comment: Yeah and if they get a hold of scripts and such it could end badly. Thanks Mikelis! I'm at home now, going to work tomorrow and I'll test your version. Thanks again

Comment: No problem. If it works, set this as the correct answer. if not - explainthe additional problems!

Comment: Thanks I'll definitely do that if it works. I reckon it should.